# gsutil error on Windows 7x64 Professional

Tags: google-cloud-storage

**Windows 7x64 Professional**

gsutil error:

```
C:\Users\Chris>gsutil.py ls
Failure: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''.
```

I have verified all settings according to the installing gsutil doc.

What am I doing wrong, or what is wrong with the installation document that should be corrected to get this to work?

**Python Version: 2.7.4**

***Edit:***

Here is the output of the gsutil debug switch:

```
C:\>python C:\gsutil\gsutil -D ls
***************************** WARNING *****************************
*** You are running gsutil with debug output enabled.
*** Be aware that debug output includes authentication credentials.
*** Do not share (e.g., post to support forums) debug output
*** unless you have sanitized authentication tokens in the
*** output, or have revoked your credentials.
***************************** WARNING *****************************
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\gsutil\gsutil", line 72, in <module>
gslib.__main__.main()
File "C:\gsutil\gslib\__main__.py", line 151, in main
  command_runner.RunNamedCommand('ver')
File "C:\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 92, in RunNamedCommand
  if self._MaybeCheckForAndOfferSoftwareUpdate(command_name, debug):
File "C:\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 160,
  in_MaybeCheckForAndOfferSoftwareUpdate
last_checked_ts = int(f.readline())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try running gsutil using:

```
python gsutil ls
```

(Also, it looks like you renamed the main gsutil script to gsutil.py. While you're of course welcome to change the code as you like, when asking for support we need you to use gsutil as distributed, without renaming or other modifications.)

If you still have the problem when running as described above, please send us the output of:

```
python gsutil -D ls
```

When you do this, please redact the value of the "Authorization:" headers in the output.

Thanks,

Mike Schwartz, Google Cloud Storage Team

Comment: Mike,
Thanks for the help. Seeing the debug helped me trace down the issue. Apparently the .last_software_update_check file had been written to my user directory but was empty. Deleting the .last_software_update_check file and re-running gsutil solved the problem!